# highlight whole row div red while error instead of just input field [php codeigniter]

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I have a form which is posted via php and if I get a error it highlights only the input field red. What I would like to do or know if there is a way to do is highlight the whole div field which contains the select field and everything and show that this whole div has a error.
Here is my html code.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="<?php if(form_error('fullname')!= null){echo ' has-error';} ?>">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">
            <?php echo lang("full_name"); ?>
        </label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="text" name="fullname" class="form-control" value="<?php if (isset($userinfo['Fullname'])) {echo $userinfo['Fullname'];} ?>" placeholder="<?php echo lang(" fullname "); ?>">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Right now it only highlights input field but I want it to highlight the whole div form-group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using bootstrap, you could try this. Please change

```
<div class="form-group">
```

to

```
<div class="form-group alert alert-danger">
```

Comment: hey I tried this,but this covers the whole box, not just the borders.

Comment: I thought you wanted the whole form-group to be highlighted. You can play around with css and make it thin if your problem is that the borders are too-thick.

Comment: But isnt it nearly impossible to push the padding to only the border of the alert ?

Comment: You can do a `padding:1px !important` and that should make it look like the border. In addition, you can style the border too in the same color and so on.

Comment: one last question , is it possible to put the error value inside the place holder as well ???

Comment: use jquery css selector to find the input and do a .attr('placeholder','error_msg');

Comment: Something like this? `$('input[name=email]').attr('placeholder','Error Message');`. Although I wouldn't recommend using placeholder to show error message. It is a pretty ugly way of doing this. Show it right under the form. It allows for scaling when you have longer messages and won't annoy the user as they type to fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<div class="form-group <?php if(form_error('fullname')!= null){echo ' bg-danger';} ?>">
    <div class="<?php if(form_error('fullname')!= null){echo ' has-error';} ?>">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">
            <?php echo lang("full_name"); ?>
        </label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="text" name="fullname" class="form-control" value="<?php if (isset($userinfo['Fullname'])) {echo $userinfo['Fullname'];} ?>" placeholder="<?php echo lang(" fullname "); ?>">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I have done is used, `.bg-danger`, one of the **Bootstrap Contextual Classes** based on the same if condition you have to apply the `has-error` class.

Comment: hey is it possible I could only get the borders highlighted instead of the whole box ???